# Absolute path with ls?

Tags: ls, command-line-interface

How can I make the `ls` command show a file's full path instead of just its filename? With all its options, there must be a way, right?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is one option for doing this.

```
ls -d $PWD/*
```

Comment: Or even better `ls -d $(pwd -P)/filename` which will resolve all symbolic links if required.

Comment: `-d` doesn't show the "file's full path" as it was stated in the question, but directories only.

Comment: @Multifix yes it does, you must add the `*`!

Answer (score 14):

This is another way for individual files:

```
readlink -e filename
```

Comment: Combining with find: `find . -exec readlink -e '{}' \;`

Comment: Use greadlink from homebrew's "coreutils" package if you are on OSX, because the readlink that comes with your laptop seems to have a different API.

Answer (score 9):

I usually use the `find` command:

```
find /dir -type f -name "*"
```

Comment: This is the first command I found of several other ones that lists only full paths of other directory than . (the present one) and excluding the directory itself from the list.

Answer (score -3):

```
ls -d "`pwd`"/*
```

that's what worked for me.
Use `*.mp3` if you want to list just mp3 files, for example. I did this to make a playlist.
keep the `""` if there's spaces in the outputs (the path to the files)